# React and d3.js - attaching event handlers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, reactjs

I'm working on a project using React for my UI and d3 for data viz.  Options set in the UI change how the chart is drawn (border, color, etc.).  The code to draw the chart is a separate library that, in production, needs to be able to draw the chart without React present.  Because of this all of the code we use to draw the chart comes from a function called in `componentDidUpdate`.

So, I've got a d3.js chart who gets updated at the very end of the React life cycle.  The issue I'm having is that in constructor of some d3.js chart elements, I attach event handlers, but these event handlers are not getting set.  I can put a break point and step into the d3 code to see they're getting hit, but when I try to use them I get nothing.  I can, however, attach the event handlers in `componentDidUpdate` and get them to work, but I don't understand why the event handlers are getting removed in the first place.  Stepping through the code I can see that the event handlers aren't being attached until after the HTML elements are present.  Any direction?  Thanks ahead of time.

```
var EventStuff= function(explodeConfig){
              attachEventHandlers:function(){
            var self = this;
            d3.selectAll("path")
                .on("click",function(d){
                    console.log("clicked paths");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I initially render the chart in `componentDidMount`, and subsequent changes to the UI render the chart in `componentDidUpdate`.  The d3 code is not using the synthetic event system of React, and the HTML elements are definitely there when I attach the event handlers.  What would keep the events from not being fired until I attach them in `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: would be useful to read the whole component

Comment: all I can tell now is that you shouldn't bind events in componentDidUpdate you'll have a listener for each update, looks like a way to create massive memory leak.
Waiting to read your code I'm using react + d3 also, I'm curious to read the way you do it.

Comment: I won't be able to put up the entire component, regrettably.  Perhaps later I can work up a mock example.  I'm pretty certain that d3 will remove and reattach the event handlers, so I don't think there would be a memory leak with each call to `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: Actually it's hard to tell without any code. Having the code of your react component would be enough to understand the way you do things. D3 is not important here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I will not be able to provide the context needed to answer the question.